# Lock mouse in window Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I want to make a FPS game in Pygame in windowed mode.

I need to be able to move my camera around for 360 degrees and more without limitation and with the hidden cursor.

I used Pygame's `set_visible` and `set_pos` but it doesn't prevent my mouse going out of the window and blocking on the screen borders.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

exit = False

while (not exit):
    pygame.mouse.set_pos = (400, 300)
    mouse_move = (0,0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_move = event.rel 
    if mouse_move != (0,0):
        print(mouse_move)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: BTW: `set_pos` is method, not variable - `pygame.mouse.set_pos((400, 300))` and it keeps mouse inside.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to call [`pygame.event.set_grab(True)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_grab) as well.

Better allow the users to exit with the Esc or another key, because they won't be able to click the x button anymore to close the window.

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        exit = True
```